# My current passport expires in June 2013, my American visa expires in June 2015. What should I do to travel to the US?

Tags: visas, planning, passports

I have a valid American visa lasting till June 2015 but my current passport expires in June 2013.

Does the American embassy transfer visas onto renewed passports or am I expected to travel with the old one?

Comment: Incredible that they would grant a visa that is valid longer than your passport! Is this normal? I've never heard of it.

Comment: @trideceth12: It is normal.

Comment: @jsj most US tourist visas are valid for 10 years.

Answer (score 17):

Here's what to do:

- Renew your passport.
- Ask the authorities to give you back the old passport, mark the visa page so they do not clip it. If they clip it then the visa is invalid.
- Whenever you want to travel to the US, take the old passport with you along with your new passport. Show them both.

Having the visa in another passport does not affect it by any means, as long as the page with the visa is not clipped. I have my own US visa in the old passport and things are fine.

Answer (score 1):

Your embassy should be able to endorse the two passports for you. It's really easy. You just have to tell them to please endorse two passports together because you still have a valid US visa.

My mom has done that for years.